# Set custom shipping method for selected product only

Tags: magento-1.7, shipping

I want to create a new custom shipping method which will be my own delivery method. I would like to show this shipping method for some of the selected products only.
Is this possible to do? Currently, I am using this extension: shipping cost per product tp work on it. But I didn't get the result that I am looking for.

Comment: Read this: http://inchoo.net/magento/custom-shipping-method-in-magento/

Comment: Yes Adash thanks, I have created the custom shipping method, How can i show this shipping method only for my selected product, Is there anything i need to do with shopping cart price rule's .

Answer (score 0):

You're going to have to edit the `getAllowedMethods` method of your shipping class. All you need to do is add an if condition to add your method to the array that method returns. So I'm imaging something like this;

```
public function getAllowedMethods()
{
    $allowed = [];
    if (in_array('YOURSKUHERE', array_column(Mage::getSingleton('checkout/cart')->getAllItems(), 'sku')) {
        $allowed[] = 'your_method_name_here';
    } 
}
```